# I want to add rows values to a data table, through the textfield using flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to add the values to the data table, that values should be the values retreived from the textfield

Values are adding to data table , but now i want add multiple rows, the rows values are set throgh Textfield , and one more is how can i use dimissiable in Datatable

//Data table//

```
DataTable(
            columns: <DataColumn>[
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("DATA"),
              ),

            ],

            rows: <DataRow>[
              DataRow(

              cells:<DataCell> [
                DataCell(
                  Text(_stext)
                ),
```

//TextField //

```
TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              maxLength: 8,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: ()
                {
                  _controller.clear();
                },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.clear,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  ),

                ),
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(20.0),
        ),
              ),
            ),),
Center(
  child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: _onPressed,
    color: Colors.redAccent,
    child: Text('Add'),
  ),
),
```

Comment: could u please share the button onPressed code? how you are updating datatable with textfield value

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
  cells:<DataCell> [
            DataCell(
              Text(_controller.text)
            ),
```

Comment: yes tried.
 but now data is not showing in the table,
i made this modification /////

 DataTable(
            columns: <DataColumn>[
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("DATA"),
              ), ],
            rows: _add
       .map((data) => DataRow(
              cells: [DataCell(
                Row(  children: <Widget>[
   Dismissible( child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(data), ),
                        key: ObjectKey(value++),
                    onDismissed: (direction){
    setState(() {
      _add.remove(data);
    });},).toList()